# Type of Battery connector of Spike Prime & essential Hub

Tags: repair, electronics, battery, spike-prime

What is the type of the 3-pin connector used to connect the Spike Prime Hub or Spike Essential Hub to the rechargeable battery? It consists of 3 pins and has a male and a female side.

I have issues in charging the battery of the Spike essential Hub and want to check if the problem is with the battery or with the Hub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about this connector:

[image: Photo of the battery unit with the connector circled in red]

then I don't think there's a name for it - besides "3 pin connector (male/female)".

If you want to diagnose it, just attach pins, hooks or clamps to the appropriate contacts, as [jncraton](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/users/708/jncraton) did [here](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/15193/3631).